# Front camera brightness get very low when start recording in custom camera

Tags: android, video-recording, screen-brightness, front-camera

I'm working in a custom video recorder which contain both front and back camera. When i start recording in back camera no problem, when i start recording in front camera brightness of the camera reduced.

i have camera switch button to change front and back camera

```
int currentCameraId;
reverseCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();

            if (currentCameraId == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
            } else {
                currentCameraId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(currentCameraId);

            setCameraDisplayOrientation(UnlVideoActivity.this, currentCameraId, mCamera);
            try {

                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    });

 public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
                                        int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
    android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
    android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;
    params.setRotation(rotation);
    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            Toast.makeText(UnlVideoActivity.this, "LAND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            Toast.makeText(UnlVideoActivity.this, "PORT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

by this way i switch the front camera when i start recoring the brightness came to low.

**code for recording**

```
  private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientationHint);
    mCamera.unlock();
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should **try manipulating camera iso settings**. *As it will let camera capture more light and you might solve your issue.*

```
    Camera camera = Camera.open();
 Camera.Parameters params =
 camera.getParameters();
 params.set("iso", "400");
 camera.setParameters(params);
```

*There can be more iso settings as 100,200,1000,auto etc*

If you want to isolate this setting only for front cam then just manipulate it if the cam in action is front cam.

Do let me know if this changed anything for you.

Comment: still i got same issue, when i turn on the front camera no issues. The brightness reduced whenever i start recording.

Comment: Did you try different iso settings ? (Greater than 400)

Comment: yeah i used but i got same issue

Comment: Try adding a capture delay of 500ms or 1second so that you give some time to cam to adapt. Let me know if it doesn't work even after that

Comment: Even i set 1 sec delayed button the same issue repeated